# Cleartext error when sending to local ip address -- Android 9

Tags: android, angular

We send an HTTP request to a device on a local network (192.168.1.1) in an Android app. The device only accepts HTTP not https requests. It was working until the Android system update yesterday (T837VVRU1BSC3). Now cleartext traffic is rejected.

I have tried the following without success:

1. `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
2. adding `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

3. changing the xml file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

These are the only suggested solutions I can find to permit cleartext traffic. Does anyone know of other solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 3):

Add the below line in the manifest in the application tag where icon, label, theme is defined

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml is okey

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```